# Cannot start new Activity from ListActivity using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, listactivity

I'm just starting to program Android Apps and I've been coding along with a book that I got. The app is just suppose to run a bunch of test activists from a list activity. I test the list activity and it worked fine. I also tried to test the first activity on the activity list and it just gets stuck trying to load it and will just keep trying to load it. My code is practically verbatim from the book besides the package name. I know that it finds the class, it's just the activity doesn't launch and I don't know why. I feel like I'm just missing something simple or overlooking a small error. Here are the three file I have for the app so far. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the intent in 
AndroidBasicStarter.java, but I'm including everything just in case it is not.

Edit: I'm having trouble loading LifeCycleTest.java. I did not code any more tests because the first one doesn't work and I don't know why.

AndroidBasicStarter.java

```
package com.dom.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class AndroidBasicStarter extends ListActivity 
{
    String tests[] = { "LifeCycleTest", "SingleTouchTest", "MultiTouchTest", 
    "KeyTest", "AccelerometerTest", "AssestsTest", "ExternalStorageTest",
    "SoundPoolTest", "MediaPlayerTest", "FullScreenTest", "RenderViewTest",
    "ShapeTest", "BitmapTest", "FontTest", "SurfaceTest"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> 
               (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tests));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view,
        int position,long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
        String testName = tests[position];

        try
        {
            Class clazz = Class.forName("com.dom.starter." + testName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidBasicStarter.this,clazz);
            startActivity(intent);//problem here maybe?
        }//end try

        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end catch
    }

}
```

LifeCycleTest.java

```
package com.dom.starter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LifeCycleTest extends Activity
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    TextView textView;

    private void log(String text)
    {
        Log.d("LifeCycleTest", text);
        builder.append(text);
        builder.append('\n');
        textView.setText(builder.toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);
    textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(builder.toString());
    setContentView(textView);
    log("Created");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        log("Resumed");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        log("Paused");

        if(isFinishing())
            log("Finishing");
    }   
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dom.starter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="AndroidBasicStarter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="LifeCycleTest"
        android:label="Life Cycle Test" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
```

Logcat

```
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{com.dom.starter/com.dom.starter.LifeCycleTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1222)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at com.dom.starter.LifeCycleTest.onCreate(LifeCycleTest.java:26)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
10-10 12:50:39.807: E/AndroidRuntime(31182):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `log("Created");` is it shown in logcat ?

Comment: It's suppose to show on screen and it's not showing up on logcat. When I try to debug it, sometimes a get a NullPointerException, but that is only sometimes.

Comment: if you directly use LifeCycleTest.class instead of clazz is it called ?

Comment: Then it does throw a NullPointerException and then exits.

Comment: can you add the logcat details of the exception

Comment: added I hope it helps. Also is there a way to get the other 11 errors after the ...11 more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in onCreate in LifeCycleTest.java it should be `super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);` instead of `super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);`

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe it was that simple. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code only `LifeCycleTest` will work, you need to add all the class in your Manifest.
change <strike>setContentView(textView);</strike>
`setContentView(R.layout.life_cycle_test);`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, that is the one with the loading problem. I don't want to go on until it's fixed.

Comment: check updated answer, you have problem with your `setContentView`

Comment: That just gives me an error. "life_cycle_test cannot be resolved or is not a field"